# TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined at got.then.res

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I played around with a package called instagram-profile-picture.

This is the code i used, straight from the npm website examples:

```
const ipp = require('instagram-profile-picture');

ipp('9gag').then(user => {
  console.log(user);
  // => https://scontent-sit4-1.cdninstagram.com/7...jpg
});
```

This used to work a couple days ago that i tested it.

Now, suddenly i get this error:

```
(node:1820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'u
rl' of undefined
    at got.then.res (C:\Users\User1\Desktop\testing npm\node_modules\insta
gram-profile-picture\index.js:15:49)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:1820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection
 id: 1)
(node:1820) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

It is very weird because i changed nothing in the code.

So i tried a new installation

```
npm init -> npm install instagram-profile-picture
```

then the same code i posted previously and i still get the same error straight from the npm example.

Comment: It's not so weird. The connection to the remote was rejected. The error tells you to use a try-catch statement. That repo hasn't been updated in a while & one of the most recent commits was titled [motherfuck](https://github.com/CodeDotJS/instagram-profile-picture/commit/f3aa48bf8e2257b9a7180f63f5f8cc336ddc21a5) you may want to go another package.

Comment: So is the error fixable or is the package dead?

Comment: `user` isn't defined, you'll need to try/catch that error or wrap it in `if(user)` and it could be fine, but you'll need to look at the lines referenced in the error. As it stands I dont' see a simple way to assist you without pulling apart the package. I'm guessing that you're missing a dependency or that you need to switch the node-version you're using ( try nvm for that )

Comment: I'd say this just doesn't work at all and I wouldn't even want to use this code in the first place. It doesn't query a rest API to get an user id and he doesn't deal with the correct schema for the JSON answer.

Comment: Instagram's entire API changed fairly recently... earlier this year, if I recall correctly. They were shifting to a more closed, enterprise-oriented system when last I checked. Part of this meant closing off a lot of their old workaround endpoints, including for things like profile pictures. Your issue may have something to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a whole npm module for this. The api is pretty simple.

```
const https = require('https');

function getUserDetails(username) {
    return new Promise(done => {
        var data = [];
        https.get(`https://www.instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1`, resp => {
            resp.on('data', chunk => data.push(chunk));
            resp.on('end', () => {
                var json = JSON.parse(data.join(''));
                done(json.graphql.user);
            });
        });
    });
}

getUserDetails('9gag').then(user=>{
    var bio = user.biography;
    var full_name = user.full_name;
    var profile_pic = user.profile_pic_url;
    console.log(bio);
    console.log(full_name)
    console.log(profile_pic);
});
```

Comment: Wow THANKS! Do i need to be logged in to use this code?

Comment: @user1584421 - nope. it works fine as is, although if you use it too frequently i'm sure insta will rate limit you. if that helped please remember to upvote or accept the answer, and if it didn't please let me know so i can fix it.

Comment: @user1584421 - if you were trying this and it didn't work it's because of a typo i missed. try with the updated code instead.

Comment: Your code works but unfortunately, it gives a link for the picture in 150X150 pixels. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @user1584421 - the larger one is located in `user.profile_pic_url_hd` (`var profile_pic = user.profile_pic_url_hd;`). there's lots of interesting stuff in the user object. you can `console.log(user)` to see what other useful data it contains.

Comment: Thanks, but even the hd one is just 320X320 pixels

Comment: well, the workaround is to sign up for instagrams api and get an api key, but i don't know if that's free or not, and dealing oauth is huge pain in the butt.

Comment: Well, even if it's not optimal, it's still a solution so thank you!

Comment: Hello! Sometimes i get an error from one line in your code and the server crashes. This is the error report " SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>), at IncomingMessage.resp.on (/app/ap
p/routes.js:109:33), at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15), at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.
js:1145:12), at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)".

Answer (score 2):

So, the problem is because you are not logged in. Basically instagram changed the query API where if you have active session(logged in), then it will show more information, if not then it will not.

So, for `9gag` if logged in:(just pasting relevant part)

```
{
  "user": {
    "pk": 259220806,
    "hd_profile_pic_url_info": {
      "url": "https://instagram.fbom20-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/777f85cb149a23d10da15f4af19ef407/5DE89E04/t51.2885-19/18645376_238828349933616_4925847981183205376_a.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbom20-1.fna.fbcdn.net",
      "width": 512,
      "height": 512
    }
  },
  "status": "ok"
}
```

But if you are logged out:

```
{
  "user": {
    "username": "9gag",
    "profile_pic_url": "https://instagram.fbom20-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/c91395418170cbb196a69ac9dea359a4/5DD372FE/t51.2885-19/s150x150/18645376_238828349933616_4925847981183205376_a.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbom20-1.fna.fbcdn.net"
  },
  "status": "ok"
}
```

But the library needs `user.hd_profile_pic_url_info.url` which is `undefined`.

**Is the library going to work with teaks?**

No unfortunately the code is quite straightforward in that library just fetching urls, you need to find one where you are providing some kind of authentication.

You can check out [node-instagram](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-instagram),

**EDIT2:** The endpoint called from the library is `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/${userid}/info/` maybe a library out there will support this api. Or you can manually authenticate yourself using the apis and hit this url yourself.

Comment: Thanks! You like One piece i see.. hehe. So is there anything that can be done with the package? Is it salvageable?